# /MyFirstApp/AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, xml

I messed up the xml file while making googles example myfirstapp with an actionbar. Please help. I am a n00b. Here is the full code for the xml file.

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Added </activity> and closed eclipse and reopened it. Works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `</activity>` for the first activity, it looks like. And the opening xml declarations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="<your package>"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="dev">
```

...

Check out the docs on the Manifest: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html